# Can't save data in WordPress via AJAX (plugin)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm working in a new plugin and I want the users use a form to send his/her email. This email would be saved in a custom table in the database.

This is the html form:

```
<form class="form-inline singup subscribe-database" action="#" method="post" data-url="<?php echo verde_product_info('extend_url') ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?php echo verde_top('language'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="database" value="<?php echo $wpdb->prefix; ?>">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

When it is sending, the js code is the next:

```
var urlplugin = jQuery('.subscribe-database').attr('data-url');
    
    jQuery('.subscribe form').submit(function() {
        var postdata = jQuery('.subscribe form').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlplugin + '/themes/php/sendmail.php',
            data: postdata, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And the file **sendmail.php** when the error happens is the next one:

```
global $wpdb;


if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    require_once('../../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}

switch ($_POST['language']) {
    case 'english':
        $success1 = 'Thanks for your subscription!';
        $error1 = 'Insert a valid email address';
        break;
    case 'spanish':
        $success1 = '&#161;Gracias por tu suscripci&oacute;n!';
        $error1 = 'Escribe un email v&aacute;lido';
        break;
    case 'french':
        $success1 = 'Merci pour votre abonnement!';
        $error1 = 'Ins&eacute;rez une adresse e-mail valide';
        break;
    case 'german':
        $success1 = 'Vielen Dank f&#252;r Ihr Abonnement!';
        $error1 = 'Legen Sie eine g&#252;ltige E-Mail-Adresse';
        break;
    case 'italian':
        $success1 = 'Grazie per il vostro abbonamento!';
        $error1 = 'Inserire un indirizzo email valido';
        break;
    case 'portuguese':
        $success1 = 'Obrigado pela sua inscri&#231;&#227;o!';
        $error1 = 'Insira um email v&aacute;lido';
        break;
}

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST['email']) {
    $table = $_POST['database'] . 'verde_emails';
    $subscriber_email = ($_POST['email']);

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = $error1;
        echo json_encode($array); 
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 1;
        $array['message'] = $success1;
        echo json_encode($array);
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'option_email' => $subscriber_email, 
            )
        )
    }
}
```

When I use the form I get the next error in the browser console:

```
200
scripts-new.js:43 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSON (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:2:4322)
    at Fn (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:15175)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:13895)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:18226)
```

But it works fine if I comment the next code in the file **sendmail.php**:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
$table, 
    array( 
        'option_email' => $subscriber_email, 
    )
)
```

but obviously, the email can't be saved in the database.

I'm lost with this error and I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Sorry for my English and thank you very much.

Comment: Is the sendmail.php loaded in plugin or child theme?

Comment: Hi, the file sendmail.php is loaded in the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this part of code and post what happens
if you are inside Wordpress you don't need this, if you are outside Wordpress you need to include more than that, wp_load.php for ex.

```
if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    require_once('../../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank for you help Codeschreiber.de

The file is loaded in the plugin. I have removed that code and the problem still happens.

Comment: the next steps are making sure, your table exists and have the right tablename (with prefix), you have the correct column name, and the column format is correct ( like "TEXT" for mail address )

Answer (score 0):

In the file sendmail.php, when it's loaded the file **wp-db.php** there isn't any error, but when the file **wp_load.php** is loaded, the error happens:

```
200
scripts-new.js:43 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSON (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:2:4322)
    at Fn (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:15175)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:13895)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:18226)
```

I have not said if before but the WordPress version is 5.9.3 and the PHP version is 8.0.8

Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).